# I don't want to re render my previous component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, react-router

I am building UI for a search engine using elasticsearch in React. I am using Pagination technique. Now if on someone clicks at result, and goes back to result list, It shows from the beginning. I want the location to be on same point where the result was clikced. how to do that ?

Here is my code:

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../components/app';
import Header from '../components/header';
import Footer from '../components/footer';
import Single from '../components/single';
import NoMatch from '../components/noMatch';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createHistory();

class Routes extends React.Component {

render() {
    return(
        <Router history={history}>
             <div className="main">
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path = "/" component={App}/>
                    <Route path = "/photo/:id/:keyw" component={Single}/> 
                    <Route path = "/*" component={NoMatch} /> 
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
}

 export default Routes;
```

and where i want component should stay the same and not re render :

**Searchresults.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazy-load';
import {
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

class SearchResults extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { results: [] }
}

render () {
    return (
        <div className="cont">
            <hr />
            <ul>
            { this.props.results.map((result) => {
                return (
                            <li key={ result._source.file_name }>
                                <LazyLoad className="lazy">
                                    <Link to={"/photo/" + result._source.file_name + "/" + result._source.keywords}>
                                        <img className="image" src={"http://localhost:3000/photos/" + result._source.file_name} alt="Search Result" />
                                    </Link>
                                </LazyLoad>
                            </li>
                        ) }) }      
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
}

SearchResults.propTypes = {
    results: PropTypes.array
}

export default SearchResults;
```

Please help me so that this component does not re render.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the same scroll position when the user returns to a page, you may want to just explicitly set the `scrollTop` on the scrolling element so that the component can be rerendered without losing the user's scroll position.

This can be done by adding the user's scroll position to the component's state, and updating the scroll position using `onScroll`.

Alternatively, using a list library that facilitates restoring the user's scroll position, such as [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List) might be a cleaner solution.